# How do you use two user inputs from python in sql statement?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, spyder

Having trouble with this bit of python code as i am not to sure on how to implement the user inputs gained into the sql statement.

```
print("What two companies would you like to compare? ")
Company1 = input("What is the first compaany you would like? ")
Company2 = input("What is the second company you would like to add? ")
comData = [Company1, Company2]
carComData = (comData) 
cursor.execute("Select * from Cars where (Car_brand like?) or (Car_brand like?) order by car_id",(carComData))
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Car_id', 'Car_Brand', 'Car_Model', 'Year', 'VIN', 'KmsTravelled', 'Price', 'Dealer_id'])
print (df)  '''
```

Comment: What trouble are you having with it exactly? What database are you using? Which driver? The example you've posted here has some obvious errors, such as using missing variable(s) in `cursor.execute(sql)`, and the whole `print (df) '''`, so please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Every database driver has (unfortunately) different syntax for binding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
cursor.execute("Select * from Cars where (Car_brand like %s) or (Car_brand like %s) order by car_id", (Company1, Company2))
```

Your problem is you had the parameters in a list instead of a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However I keep getting "OperationalError: near "%": syntax error". I realise it is a cut and paste of your code but I am not sure where to go tbh.

Comment: try `cursor.execute("Select * from Cars where Car_brand like ? or Car_brand like ? order by car_id", (Company1, Company2))` and that will probably work